# Issue in checking out repo in GIT in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit, ubuntu-server

I have a git repo in my Ubuntu server set up.

I want to checkout that repo on my windows machine into eclipse.

I have installed EGIT plugin my eclipse.

I tried checking importing the files from using the plugin by choosing the URI option in eclipse and got an Unknown Host Exception.

These are the setting i gave:

```
1) URI  : user@hostname:/path/to/repo
2) Host : hostname
3) Repository Path : /path/to/repo
4) Protocol :SSH
5) Port : 22
6) user : username
7) pwd : password
```

Is there any place that in need to enter the ip address.
The server is on my lan and I can access and work on my repo using putty.
What info is missing here.

The error msg is also as shown:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_with_remote_Repositories) you need to use a full URI.

```
URI: ssh://user@hostname:/path/to/repo
```

Comment: I tried the same and got the same error message.I have updated the question by attaching the error screenshot.

Comment: Thanks will try this and get back.But If i have to test the connectivity to my Ubuntu Server using this hostname and user to check before I can try this in eclipse how can I test this.Coz if I try to test the connectivity with the ip address of the server it shows that its connected.I want the same kind of confirmation with the hostname.